# How can we salvage a poorly pruned mature pear tree?

Tags: fruit-trees, pruning, tree-care, pear

I just had a company prune my mature pear tree yesterday. But I think they did it all wrong. I asked for the top to be trimmed down as much as possible and prune around power lines and over our neighbor's property.

The tree is over 2 car garage stories high and diminishing the amount and size of fruit on the tree.

What they did was just snip part of the highest branch and basically cut off all the lower large branches rather than prune them.

What can I do now?  The tree looks like an arrow shooting to the sky and very sad looking with no branches spreading out horizontally.

We're very sad about what's happened to our tree.  Is there any way to save it?

I was hoping the pruning would produce more quality pears that are reachable to pick. They were too high up before and small since the tree was so big and tall. Now I wouldn't be able to get any pears if they grow next year.

Sorry, I'm new to this site.  Can't seem to figure out how to post pictures.

Comment: Do you have before and after pictures of the tree that you can post?

Comment: We really need some more information even to speculate.  What kind of pear, how old is the tree, did it bear every year or every other year, pictures..

Comment: The easiest way for you to upload a picture is to put the file on your desktop, click the ['add image' icon](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bK9Wv.png) at the top of your post (when editing), and then drag your picture from the desktop into the [box that comes up](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3nBC.png), and click 'Add picture'. Repeat for each photo.

Comment: We need more details and photographs to answer this question properly. Stop by [chat] if you need assistance with uploading the photos; once edited, your question will be reviewed for reopening. Thanks!